# Fix the display of output

Tags: python

My code works perfectly fine, but I am having trouble trying to make the output look like the one on the picture. I need to have the exact same spaces (exact display). I don't need to alter colors, just spaces and display. Please help! [PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Y52.png)

```
name = input("Enter employee's name: ")

hours = float(input("Enter number of hours worked in a week: "))

payRate = float(input("Enter hourly pay rate: "))

fedTaxWithholdingRate = float(input("Enter federal tax withholding rate (ex. 0.12): "))

stateTaxWithholdingRate = float(input("Enter state tax withholding rate (ex. 0.06): "))

grossPay = hours * payRate

fedTaxWithholding = grossPay * fedTaxWithholdingRate

stateTaxWithholding = grossPay * stateTaxWithholdingRate

totalDeduction = fedTaxWithholding + stateTaxWithholding

netPay = grossPay - totalDeduction

print("Employee Name: " + name) 

print("Hours Worked: " + str(hours))

print("Pay Rate: $" + str(payRate)) 

print("Gross Pay: $" + str(grossPay))

print("Deductions:\n")

print(" Federal Withholding (" + str(fedTaxWithholdingRate * 100) + \
 "%): $" + str(int(fedTaxWithholding * 100) / 100.0))

print(" State Withholding (" + str(stateTaxWithholdingRate * 100) + "%):" + \
 " $" + str(int(stateTaxWithholding * 100) / 100.0))

print(" Total Deduction:" + " $" + \
 str(int(totalDeduction * 100) / 100.0))

print("Net Pay:" + " $" + str(int(netPay * 100) / 100.0))
```

Comment: If you print the name then you won't display exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

add `" " * number_of_spaces + "your string"` in some places

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24116719).